# R: Return a vector for each row of a matrix which lists what colum the value x is in

Tags: r, matrix

Okay, sorry I know this sounds unnecessarily confusing. I am basically looking to return a vector of elements equal to the number of rows with each element specifying where in the matrix the specified outcome occurred.

```
library(gtools)
(A <- permutations(3, 3))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1    3    2
[3,]    2    1    3
[4,]    2    3    1
[5,]    3    1    2
[6,]    3    2    1
```

Using the unknown function `foo` would return:

```
foo(A, match=1)
[1] 1 1 2 3 2 3
foo(A, match=2)
[1] 2 3 1 1 3 2
```

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: You can also do something nasty as `apply(A, 1, function(x) which(x == 1))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg is there an easy way to make `apply` this return `0` instead of `integer(0)` if the value is not found?

Comment: You could make a condition, for example `apply(A, 1, function(x) if(length(which(x == 1)) == 0) 0 else which(x == 1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
foo <- function(mat, match=1){
  indx <- which(mat==match, arr.ind=TRUE)
  indx[order(indx[,1]),2]
}

foo(A, 1)
#[1] 1 1 2 3 2 3
foo(A,2)
#[1] 2 3 1 1 3 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `max.col` and some indexing of the matrix:

```
> max.col(A==1)
[1] 1 1 2 3 2 3
> max.col(A==2)
[1] 2 3 1 1 3 2
```

Comment: It is not clear if there are multiple `1s` per row, what would be the desired outcome.  In that case, `max.col` with default  `ties.method` as `random` chose the `random` index For example `A[2,2] <- 1; max.col(A==1)
#[1] 1 2 2 3 2 3;  foo(A,1)#
[1] 1 1 2 2 3 2 3`

Comment: @akrun - that is true - the `ties.method=` would have to be set in the case of multiple values. The example given was a permutation though, so I didn't think too deeply about other possible use cases.

Comment: I do occasionally use `max.col`.  I wish if it had an option for `ties.method=everything' or `all`.