# How to create a new vector from inputs in a list of vectors?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, feature-engineering

[image]

How could I make another column called "Purpose" that takes in the name of these variables if their input is "Yes"?
Note: there are observations that don't have a "Yes" input at all.

Thankfully, I already have working code:

```
CD$PURPOSE <- ifelse(CD$NEW_CAR == "Yes", "New_Car", 
                     ifelse(CD$USED_CAR == "Yes", "Used_Car",
                            ifelse(CD$FURNITURE == "Yes", "Furniture",
                                   ifelse(CD$`RADIO/TV` == "Yes", "Radio/TV", 
                                          ifelse(CD$EDUCATION == "Yes", "Education", 
                                                 ifelse(CD$RETRAINING == "Yes", "Retraining", "None"))))))
```

I would, however, prefer to use something else. My gut instinct says that this isn't best practice.

Here is an unfinished attempt which throws an error:

```
PurposeCols <- c("NEW_CAR", "USED_CAR", "FURNITURE", "RADIO/TV", "EDUCATION", "RETRAINING") 
Purpose <- vector(mode="character", length=1000)
possible_i= 1:1000


for (1:1000){
for (i in PurposeCols){
  if (CD[,i] == "Yes") {
    Purpose[i] = "Yes"
   }
  
  }
}
```

The reason I want to change the code is that I realize I could potentially have many more variables that I would need to do a similar process on.

Thank you.

Comment: Think I've dealt with this sort of thing before - like `colnames(CD)[max.col(CD == "Yes")]` or similar - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957318/r-return-a-vector-for-each-row-of-a-matrix-which-lists-what-colum-the-value-x-i/28957469 for instance.

Comment: In your code, replace the entire loop with `CD$purpose <- PurposeCols[apply(CD[PurposeCols],1, function(x) match("Yes", x))]`